# pgadmin 4 - cannot use select all and undo

Tags: editor, undo, pgadmin-4

I have used pgadmin 4 for months now.
but from about a month ago, suddenly on pgadmin 4 editor, I couldnt do ctrl + a (select all) and ctrl + z (undo).
I still can do other shortcut though like ctrl + c and ctrl + v.
this is not fatal, but very hindering in my work because I couldnt do select all and undo.
and this happened too on the new installation of pgadmin 4 on my vps server. So I think this is now a default behavior on pgadmin 4 ?
I can confirm that ctrl + a and ctrl + z worked on other tabs in the same browser, so it only happened on pgadmin 4.

is there anyway to make these shortcuts to work again ?
any setting that I might accidentally trigger maybe ?

thx.